# Product of limits when one is zero

Tags: limits

We have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, such that  $\lim_{ x\to 0}f(x)=0$. 
Does it mean that the limit of the product would always be zero? 
$$\lim_{ x\to 0}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{ x\to 0}f(x) \times \lim_{ x\to 0}g(x)=0$$

Comment: With $f(x)=x$, use $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: limit of the product is the product of the limit, as long as the limits aren't zero and infinity. If they are zero and infinity, then the limit remains an indeterminate form. So to answer your question, no, if $g(x)$ approaches infinity, the product may or may not approach $0$

Answer (score 1):

Writing

$$\lim_{ x\to 0}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{ x\to 0}f(x) \lim_{ x\to 0}g(x)$$ is not legit ! This identity can be used only when the two limits on the right exist.

So you should ask one of the following questions:

1. does $\lim_{ x\to 0}f(x)=0$ imply $\lim_{ x\to 0}f(x)g(x)=0$ ?
2. does $\lim_{ x\to 0}f(x)=0$ imply $\lim_{ x\to 0}f(x) \lim_{ x\to 0}g(x)=0$ ?

In both cases, the answer is negative.

Anyway, if you mean that the first identity does hold, the the two limits do exist and the claim is true.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not always the case. It could be zero, it could be another number, or the limit could not exist.

For example, with $f(x)=x$, use $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$.